# Screen tearing in Chromium browser

Tags: chromium, visual-artifacts

There is some type of image corruption or screen tearing in chromium-browser: 59.0.3071.109-0ubuntu0.16.04.1291. It's hard to describe, but it affects the entire browser and not just YouTube videos. I've tried changing some options in about:configs (I don't remember which ones), but it still happens.

[image: Screenshot of tearing]

Graphics card: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading the Linux Mint 18.2 release notes and they recommend to uninstall `xserver-xorg-video-intel` for other video issues. They state that:

```
The legacy driver is no longer maintained and only useful for the old i800x and i900x family of chipsets.
```

After rebooting I haven't noticed any screen issues or artifacts with chromium-browser.